# Finding a list of memory mapped objects in windows

Tags: windows, memory, shared

I'm planning on using the CreateFileMapping() function with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE for hFile so that the storage is backed by the paging file. There could be several processes that are creating these mapped objects. I also need to run another process which can just read from these mapped objects. Is there a way for this process to programmatically fetch a list of memory mapped objects ? Even if it were a system command that the process could run and then parse to figure out the list of handles, it would work.

I have seen a few questions similar to this on stack overflow, but could not find a concrete answer. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: No, it is your responsibility to co-ordinate the names for the file mappings so that the reading process knows what names to use.  (One possible approach would be a master file mapping with a known name, containing the names of all the other mappings.)

Answer (score 2):

While it is technically possible to get the [list of handles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) in a process and then try to figure out which handles are memory mapped files, you quickly end up having to call undocumented functions and you also have to deal with the [named pipe hang issue](https://forum.sysinternals.com/discussion-howto-enumerate-handles_topic19403_post99580.html).

I would recommend that you take a different approach:

- Give the mappings a name so you can open them by name. This might require a mapping with a known name that just contains a list of the other names.
- Use handle inheritance or `DuplicateObject` to get the handles into the other process. Use a named pipe or window messages to send the handle value of the duplicated handle to the other process.
- Just use normal files. `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` might help.